# I can't get last selected date to show up in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this script

> var day_name = $("#d_day_name").val();
>               var month_name = $("#d_month_name").val();
>               day_name = day_name.split(",");
>               month_name = month_name.split(",");

```
        $(".datepick").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            dayNamesMin: [day_name[0],day_name[1],day_name[2],day_name[3],day_name[4],day_name[5],day_name[6]],
            monthNames: [month_name[0],month_name[1],month_name[2],month_name[3],month_name[4],month_name[5],month_name[6],month_name[7],month_name[8],month_name[9],month_name[10],month_name[11]],
            closeText: $("#d_close_text").val(),
            prevText: $("#d_prev_text").val(),
            nextText: $("#d_next_text").val(),
            currentText: $("#d_current_text").val()
        });
        $("#btnAddPrice").click(function () {
            var $tbody = $("#tblPrices tbody"),
                h = $tbody.find("tr:last").find("td:first").html(),
                i = (h === null) ? 0 : parseInt(h);
            $tbody.append('<tr id="tr_' + (i + 1) + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td><input type="text" name="date_from[]" class="text w80 pointer datepick" readonly="readonly" /></td><td><input type="text" name="date_to[]" class="text w80 pointer datepick" readonly="readonly" /></td><td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="text_small align_right" /></td><td><input type="text" name="weekprice[]" class="text_small align_right" /></td><td><a class="icon icon_delete" href="#" onclick="$(\'#tr_' + (i + 1) + '\').remove(); return false;">delete</a></td></tr>');
```

$tbody.find("tr:last").find(".datepick").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
            });

And i was trying to put new Date(+1) so the datepicker will start with the last selected date, into THE datepicker instead of dateFormat but that don't work. And i can't seem to figure out what i can do to make this work.
I have looked all over THE net, but did not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the table cell (`td`) rather than the datepicker (`input`). This means you need to use `.val()`. If you reference `td` and use `.html()`, it will return `<input class='datepick' />` since you are getting the contents of the cell.

To find the current value in the datepicker, you need to do this:

```
 $tbody.find("tr:last").find("td:first").find(".datepick").val()
```

To set the value of another datepicker, use:

```
$tbody.find("tr:last").find(".datepick").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"}).val('PUT DATE HERE');
```

Hope this helps!

***EDIT:***

REFER TO THIS: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

To change default date, do this:

`$tbody.find("tr:last").find("td:first").find(".datepick").datepicker({ defaultDate: +1 });`

Comment: That doesn't work, i've tried it all. there is only one date picker that sets the date, and i believe it makes a circle so it always starts at today.

Comment: Sounds like you are referring to the defaultDate.  I made an edit to my initial post.

Comment: Nope all off that not working it all starts with the present day and not with the last given date. In the second input it also starts with the present day and i would it to start with the date of the first input date. If i alter something it makes a new table but than date picker doesn't show up.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle.net and I will assist

Comment: I would like to but i have only php and there it is html.